# Article is sitting on top of content instead of within content in html page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn about HTML 5 and layout. I figured the best way to do this would be to update my personal web site. I'm trying to make my personal web site looks like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Welcome               [black background]                                        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Title (with big font) [white background]                                        |
| subtitle                                                                        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| links here            [blue background]                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| more links here       [light blue background]                                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                 |
| Page Title Goes Here  [white background]                                        |
|                                                                                 |
| ----------------------      --------------------------------------------------- |
| | [gray background]  |      | [gray background]                               | |
| | Some content will  |      | INTRODUCTION                                    | |
| | go here            |      | A blurb will go here                            | |
| |---------------------      --------------------------------------------------- |
|                                                                                 |
| [white background should be behind everythign in this area                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In an attempt to do this, I have the following HTML 5 code:

```
<body>
  <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:70%;">
    <nav style="background-color:black; line-height:34px; height:34px;">
      <div style="vertical-align:middle; padding:0px 12px; color:white;">
        Welcome!
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div style="height:130px; width:100%; background-color:#fff; display:table;">
      <div style="vertical-align:middle; color:#000; display:table-cell; padding-left:12px;">
        <h1>My Site</h1>
        <h2>Thank you for visiting</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav style="background-color:#085394; line-height:32px;">
      <div style="vertical-align:middle; padding:0px 12px; color:white;"></div>            
    </nav>

    <nav style="background-color:#597eaa; line-height:32px; padding:0px 12px;">
      <div style="vertical-align:middle; color:white;">

      </div>
    </nav>

    <div style="padding:12px 30px; background-color:#fff;">
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>My Page</h1>
        </header>

        <div id="leftContent">
          Some content will go here
        </div>  

        <div id="rightContent">
          <section>
            <header>INTRODUCTION</header>
            A blurb will go here
          </section>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I also have the following relevant styles defined:

```
#leftContent, #rightContent {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:8px;
}
.leftContent {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    background-color:lightgray;
    padding-right:12px;
}
.rightContent {
    width: 67%;
    float: right;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pt5Gv/

Everything is close. The problem that I have right now is that the white area below the `nav` content does not extend past the content in the `article` tag. What do I need to do to make the white content continue. Right now, it acts almost like the `article` content is sitting on top of everything, instead of within the main content area.

Comment: do you have a fiddle?  did you clear it?

Comment: Well, first off, you have .rightcontent and .leftcontent slecting classes, rather than ids. Change .rightcontent to #rightcontent and .leftcontent to #leftcontent.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the following css

```
body 
{
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not clear after the floats
You need to add

```
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</article>  <----- before closing the article
```